# Add data to healthkit from Apple Watch and iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, healthkit

I'm working on an water-app at the moment that can send information to healtkit from the iPhone and the Apple Watch. I have successful setup the healtkit authorization and i can send data to healtkit.

When i'm sending data from the Apple Watch to healtkit it works fine, al my data entries are vissible in the graph. The strange thing is when i add data from my iPhone that the graph will be overwritten with the iPhone data. The watch entries are still in "show data"

When then i'm adding from my Apple Watch it won't update the graph but the entries are also in "show data".

I'm using a sharedfiel (HealtKitManager.swift) file for the healthkit authorization and the "AddWater" function.

```
import Foundation
import HealthKit

class HealtKitManager: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = HealtKitManager()

private override init() {}

let healthStore  = HKHealthStore()

func authorizeHealthKit(_ completion: @escaping((_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void)){

        let waterType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .dietaryWater)!
        let allTypes = Set([waterType])

        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: allTypes, read: allTypes) { (success, error) in
            print("Authorization \(success)")
            completion(success, error)
        }
    }

func addWater(mL :  Double){

    let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .dietaryWater)
    let quantityUnit = HKUnit(from: "mL")
    let quantityAmount = HKQuantity(unit: quantityUnit, doubleValue: mL)

    let now = Date()

    let sample = HKQuantitySample(type: quantityType!, quantity: quantityAmount, start: now, end: now)

    let correlationType = HKObjectType.correlationType(forIdentifier: HKCorrelationTypeIdentifier.food)

    let waterCorrelationForWaterAmount = HKCorrelation(type: correlationType!, start: now, end: now, objects: [sample])

    self.healthStore.save(waterCorrelationForWaterAmount, withCompletion: { (succes, error) in

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("error")
        }
    })

}

}
```

in my ViewController and my InterfaceController i've connected buttons to write a "default" value to healtkit:

```
@IBAction func addGlassAction(_ sender: Any) {

    healtKitManager.addWater(mL: 100)

}
```

and

```
@IBAction func add50ml() {
   healtKitManager.addWater(mL: 50)
}
```

Why is the iPhone app "the boss"?

Is there someone who can help me in te right direction?